# Replac Ampersand with question mark

Tags: .htaccess

For some reason the controller is querying to the http server with & in the middel insted of ?. If I replace it with ? It works fine. Can some one write a htaccess code to replace ? After the final "/login.php& redirect = " to some thing line "login.php? redirect*****"

Comment: 'for some reason' is the HTTP standard.

Answer (score 1):

Put this somewhere appropriate in your htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)&(.*)$ /$1?$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: This URL 1 is not working URL 2 is working fine. So the condition should be  "after byod.php remove ampersand and put question mark" only for byod.php not for other php scrips 

    1.   http://10.168.4.253/byod.php&redirect=www.google.com.sg/search?q=cars........

    2.   http://10.168.4.253/byod.php?redirect=www.google.com.sg/search?q=cars........


Is this possible using htaccess

Comment: @user1564173 I put these rules in a blank htaccess file on a newly installed apache, and it does exactly what you've asked, which also includes **login.php**, so now you want it to only apply to **byod.php** you need to replace the first match before **&** (the `.*`) to byod.php

Comment: This is a lifesaver... After switching from default to custom permalinks on my wordpress site, some of my php GET variables stopped working when REQUEST_URI was no longer returning a url that ended with ?page_id=