# replace ampersand with question mark for only one php

Tags: .htaccess

This URL 1 is not working URL 2 is working fine. So the condition should be  "after byod.php remove ampersand and put question mark" only for byod.php not for other php scrips

```
1.   http://10.168.4.253/byod.php&redirect=www.google.com.sg/search?q=cars........

2.   http://10.168.4.253/byod.php?redirect=www.google.com.sg/search?q=cars........
```

Is this possible using htaccess

Comment: Why not fix the problem instead? Find on what page the ampersand is being used and replace it with the proper question mark. Querystrings need to start with question marks so the second one is proper, the first is just plain wrong as ampersand is only used to separate variables while already within a querystring. You shouldn't have to coddle broken code.

Comment: This is a query issue with the CISCO controller which we cannot be change

Answer (score 1):

Like the [previous question that you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730114/replac-ampersand-with-question-mark), if you want it only to apply to `byod.php` you need to specify that in the match:

```
RewriteRule ^byod\.php&(.*)$ /byod.php?$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably dig for `mod_rewrite` or similar tool for you webserver.